# Error check if user enters a letter or number

Tags: c, char, letter, error-checking

I'm error checking for letters. If a letter is entered then its suppose to print out error and exit. If its a number then it's suppose to run the statement (which I didn't put in the code since its irrelevant at the moment) under the if. When I enter a number it should run the if statement but when I enter a letter or a number it goes to the else statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{
  int x;
  printf("Enter up to 10 positive integer ending with EOF:\n");

while((scanf("%d",&x)) != EOF && x < 100){


if( isdigit(x) ){
//statement
}

else{
printf("error, wrong input\n");
return 0;
}

}


if(x >= 100)
printf("error, wrong input\n");


return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C compiler doesn't care about that indenting but it's pretty confusing for me.

Comment: You don't need to check with `isdigit`. `scanf` with `%d` already checks whether the input can be parsed as an integer. And also converts the input characters to an integer on success. It will return `1` if the input can be parsed as an integer and`0` otherwise. So then you only need to check `if (x >= 0 && x <= 9)` to do an equivalent `isdigit` check (though I suspect you really just want to check whether the input is an integer and not whether it is a digit).

Answer (score 1):

You want `isdigit` to check a `char` , please change `scanf` to :

```
while((scanf("%c",&x)) != EOF && x < 100){  // yes x is an int, but here you want a char
```